# Meeting room or meetings room

Tags: grammatical-number

A friend from work asked me why he should write meetings room, instead of meeting room. For him it made more sense to use the plural word meetings as several meetings were held in that place. I know it is meeting room, but could not explain him the difference. I would like to know if meetings room is correct or not.

Comment: 'Meeting room' is how you say it usually in the US.

Comment: Surely there's only one meeting there at a time! 'Meeting' is serving as an adjective, and you don't normally make adjectives plural (unless there is a special reason).  Would your colleague talk about a "computers room" because it has multiple computers?